# count multiple relations results with a single Parse query

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I'm having a very simple setup with `_User` entity having a `likes` Relation with itself (reflective).

A common use case is list users.
I'm listing very few users (ex: 15), but i would also like to display the amount of likes he has.

Following [standard suggested technique from Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-retrieve-all-relation-linked-to-pfobject-via-rest-api) that would require a query for each of the 15 `_User`(s).
I don't think this is acceptable, maybe 2 queries are enough:

- first one getting the first 15 `_User`(s)
- second one getting the amount of `likes` each of the `_User` haves

But I have no idea if that's even possible with Parse API, so I'm asking for help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column is a relation, then yes, getting the count will require a query per user.

If you expect the number of likes per user to be low (<100 is my semi-arbitrary rule of thumb), you could instead model likes as an array of pointers.

With that, you can know the count just by having the record in hand (i.e. `someUser.get("likes").length`).  Even better, query include will eagerly fetch the related users...

```
userQuery.include("likes");
userQuery.find().then(function(users) {
    if (users.length) {
        var someUser = users[0];
        var likes = someUser.get("likes");
        if (likes.length) { // see, we can get the count without query
            var firstLike = likes[0];  // we can even get those other users!
            var firstLikeEmail = firstLike.get("email");
        }
    }
});
```

Otherwise, using relations, you're stuck with another query...

```
userQuery.find().then(function(users) {
    if (users.length) {
        var someUser = users[0];
        var likes = someUser.get("likes");
        return likes.query().count();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}).then(function(count) {
    console.log("the first user has " + count + " likes");
});
```

Comment: thanks for confirmation, I was hoping there was another way. I'll try and use arrays